# Generic Nested typescript Type keyof

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics, types, typescript-typings

I am trying to create a deep nested "keyof" type in typescript, but as soon as i go deeper than one level, typescript complains that the object is invalid.
Can someone please explain me what i am doing wrong here typewhise?

Here is what i tried: [Typescript Playground Nested Keyof type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqUCGA7AzgM2gFtgpcAeNAPjgF44AFTWAS0wBtyAoOOAJWABjaABNyAa2CII+RsxhtO1ADRwAFADcOAV2AAuOLhhQW2AOYBKOjRyIqXe11CRYCZKgDyYBRDyUa9ADePHBgUBBgAIwGRibmANwhggAWLOwiAMrA7EIw0LgA-AaBcADakohwpnAVMugAukXqIbyxpmZwAD4tZW3m9V09amrZwCTYMDHG7Ra0NBoQLCJW3by8Xj5+aOVS9fZrcBYAvom8xjgExKS4BhgXhFAkZP6JR1xO4NDwSCjowEYAWQgImydDgwV4RAgGhYwAAcpgSFM4mZToYYPIAJLYQhNQIKJHolHxNwoZHtEnhCBEckJI6lepcN5cYR4eAQABGACtonANixfBQ0P8YECQewAuCQmEIryAOQwEVy5RJVLpLI5QR5MjFHpQmHwxH6OAKkUAJmVPSMWJxEF1B14MqiBlNRgAzJaHXAUmlMqMtfl7V6ECxCXKAHSKowAFk9DqOKq95zwDyeN3BbwOmbgCZCycuj2uxV4uaOQA)

I tried to google for this issue but didn't find any answer.

i expect the type to be working properly but as soon as i go one nested level deeper i get issues. I hope some typescript expert can explain me what i am doing wrong

Comment: The problem is that `startInfo` is an array and you try to map through the keys of the array, not of its elements. Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wja26W) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Please [edit] to add the code as plaintext in the question itself, otherwise it doesn’t count as a [mre].  I would do it for you but it’s it clear that anyone but you has the copyright to do so

Comment: wonderflame your example worked perfectly fine! Please write an answer explaining what you did here. i really appriciate it!
jcalz i had issues with the editor freezing and that's why i added a links.
It would be awesome if you can help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `startInfo` is an array and you are basically mapping through the keys of the array itself, not the keys of its elements. The easiest fix would be to check whether the type is an array and in that case, map through the keys of its elements, otherwise just map through the keys of the type.

To determine whether a type is an array, we going to check if it extends `readonly unknown[]`. `readonly` is crucial to be able to handle read-only arrays, since regular arrays are *subsets* of read-only arrays:

```
// true
type Case1 = number[] extends readonly number[] ? true : false;
// false
type Case2 = readonly number[] extends number[] ? true : false;
```

To get the type of the array's elements we are going to use [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
// 1 | 2 | 3
type Case3 = [1, 2, 3][number
```

Let's combine all together:

```
type Options<T> = {
  prop1: string;
  childSelectors?: T extends readonly unknown[]
    ? {
        [K in keyof T[number]]?:
          | string
          | [string]
          | ((element: string) => void)
          | Options<T[number][K]>;
      }
    : {
        [K in keyof T]?:
          | string
          | [string]
          | ((element: string) => void)
          | Options<T[K]>;
      };
  transformers: Transformers<T>;
};
```

However, the code is way too repetitive, thus by using [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) we will create a generic parameter in which we will store either `T` or `T[number]`:

```
type Options<T> = {
  prop1: string;
  childSelectors?: (T extends readonly unknown[] ? T[number] : T) extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]?: (
    string |
    [string] |
    ((element: string) => void) |
    Options<U[K]>
  ) } : never;
  transformers: Transformers<T>;
}
```

Much better!

Testing:

```
const obj1: Options<TestModel> = {
  prop1: 'test',
  childSelectors: {
    movieName: 'test2',
    startInfo: {
      prop1: 'test3',
      childSelectors: {
        time: '' // no error
      },
      transformers: {}
    }
  },
  transformers: {},
}
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqUCGA7AzgM2gFtgpcAeNAPjgF44AFTWAS0wBtyAoOOAJWABjaABNyAa2CII+RsxhtO1ADRwAFADcOAV2AAuOLhhQW2AOYBKOjRyIqXe11CRYCZKgDyYBRDyUa9ADePHBgUBBgAIwGRibmANwhggAWLOwiAMrA7EIw0LgA-AZqaHCgMMDYIrhwUMCYIr7siHDa2OLYEADu2ADaALpwBei92NpEAEakgwZoVuWV1XCm+KRwAKpDcIFwvQDSy9hwktKy6-1F6iG8saZmcAA+17u35oNPvLxqatnAJNgwGLGO5WWg0DQQFgiKwfT5eHx+db7fr2XhWAC+cAM2GAGlIiV4xhwBGIpFwsyweEIUBIZH8iXRXCc4Gg8CQKHQwCMAFkICJsnRtiEiBANCxgAA5TAkIFxMwEwwweQASWwhEuOwUMsVcvibhQsruevCECIhoScHRAy4jK4wjw8AgEwAVtE4PCWL4KGguTBefz2AEhbwwhE3QByCpGcPKJKpdJZHKCPJkAzBT5wEViyXS-RwSO+gBMMeeRhVaogaeeIfCUQMBaMAGYSxneCk0plfsn8lXW58tXnw+G4AB6EdwTplKDhKDVy2xvtEqmk1PbRkZ9fzkJLkk0slp9Gx9FAA)

Answer (score 0):

```
**You can do like this hope it will work.**

export type Transformers = Record <string, any>;

type ChildSelectors = {
  movieName?: string;
  startInfo?: {
    prop1: string;
    childSelectors: {
      time: string;
    };
    transformers: {};
  };
};

export type Options = {
  prop1: string;
  childSelectors?: ChildSelectors;
  transformers: Transformers;
};



const obj1: Options = {
  prop1: 'test',
  childSelectors: {
    movieName: 'test2',
    startInfo: {
      prop1: 'test3',
      childSelectors: {
        time: '.test4',
      },
      transformers: {},
    },
  },
  transformers: {},
};
```